Making the best choices when designing an interface
hoping for advice. How do I make the best choices in selecting the right UI elements to use when it comes to designing an interface? This might sound vague so I'll give some examples.
I designed an interface:  and I thought it through and it looks fine. But some other designer comes along and suggests another interface: and I was kicking myself for not thinking of it.
So is there a methodology or mindset that I should have when it comes to choosing the best elements to use?
Thank you in advance for any advice.

Allow me to rephrase your question:

Is there a methodology or mindset that a designer should have when it comes to choosing the best UI elements for designing a user interface?

Short answer: Good designers develop "taste" that builds over time; it's a blend of "art & science"
My advice: Read Apple HIG, follow UI Design Heuristics, and consider Fitt's Law
Some more advice:

Be curious and learn from other products in your niche/domain. Notice that there are common page layouts (e.g. table, tiles);
Define each component and assess their pros and cons to better understand them;
Most importantly, emphasize with user's workflow. In short you want to make sure that your UI matches their expectations.


The general principle here is to show redundant graphical elements in only one dimension, rows or columns. If you need more space, click to the next page.
The empty screen space can be used for static information, or to control the location in a hierarchical structure or a database cursor.
The win 11 control panel is a good example of this.
But trying to maximize real estate used by packing the screen with a table is very confusing to the user.
